# Why Struts2 submit tag with action attribute doesn't change page URL

Tags: jsp, struts2

Here is my jsp code:

```
<s:form method="POST" action="foo/bar">
    <s:submit value="Update"/>
    <s:submit value="Reverse" action="foo/bar/reverse"/>
</s:form>
```

jsp page Struts2 theme is `simple`.

Here is my struts mapping:

```
    <action name="foo/bar"
        class="my.package.BarAction">
        <result>/foo/bar.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="foo/bar/reverse"
        class="my.package.BarAction"
            method="reverse">
        <result>/foo/bar.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

So when I first go on page, url in browser address string is `localhost:myapp/foo/bar.action` when I click submit button, page reloads, url becomes the same. But when I click on "reverse" button, page reloads, but url still the same. I think url should change to `localhost:myapp/foo/bar/reverse.action`, as "reverse" button is mapped on that action. So why doesn't url in browser address input change? Not that I wanted url in address string to change on "reverse" pressed, but it seems to be reasonable to happen and I'm curious why it doesn't.

Struts version is 2.13.5.1

EDIT1:

I checked in google dev tools, and when I press "reverse" button the request is sent to "http://localhost/myapp/foo/bar.action", not to "http://localhost/myapp/foo/bar/reverse.action"

EDIT2:

I tried removing action mapping for `foo/bar/reverse` action and now I get 404 error when I press "reverse" button, saying that there is no action mapped for action name foo/bar/reverse. Also looking at the request I found that the following form data is passed in the request: `action:foo/bar/reverse=Reverse`

So it appears that for the client, struts2 behaves as if request was sent to `foo/bar.action` (which is where it is actually sent), but later struts executes a different action.

EDIT3:

I changed result in struts mapping to `foo/blabla.jsp` for `foo/bar/reverse` action and now after I press `reverse` button, i get contents of `blabla.jsp` but url in browser is still the same.

I guess, it appears that it's just how Struts2 work.

Comment: Please show your struts.xml: constants, packages etc

Comment: @AndreaLigios no constans, package name = foo, extends struts-default

Comment: It is how S2 works. The `action` from `submit` won't be in url bar.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Struts2 documentation](http://struts.apache.org/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-ActionNames):

> **Action Names With Slashes**
>
> If your action names have slashes in them (for example,
>
> ```xml
> <action name="admin/home" class="tutorial.Admin"/>
> ```
>
> ) you need to specifically
>   allow slashes in your action names via a constant in the struts.xml
>   file by specifying
>
> ```xml
> <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>.
> ```
>
> See JIRA [Issue WW-1383](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-1383) for discussion as there are
>   side effects to setting this property to true.

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. I actually have this property set to true.

Comment: @dhblah then why have you answered "no constans" ? :|

Comment: sorry, it appeared that foo-struts.xml i looked in was imported by another struts.xml which was actually used by struts and it had that constant defined. I found it by full text search by constant name.